# Where can I find the history of changes in AzureDev Ops Calendar?

Tags: azure-devops, calendar

My team added some events in AzureDev Ops Calendar (The location is AzureDev Ops / Boards / Calendar) but the events were deleted. I want to find out who deleted the events. Is there any way to see log/history of changes for Calendar in Azure DevOps?

I checked all the buttons and links on the page, but I couldn't find anything related.

Comment: This is an extension? At least I don't have a calendar

Answer (score 2):

The calendar stores its data in extension storage. There's no history on that.

And the calendar extension doesn't store any logs in storage either.